# Copying dataframes columns into another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2` where `df1` has 9 columns and `df2` has 8 columns. I want to replace the first 8 columns of `df1` with that of `df2`. How can this be done? I tried with `iloc` but not able to succeed.

Following are the files:

https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/842516/tpkA0t2vAtkrqKTb/df1.csv for `df1`

https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/842517/8XpizwCAX79p9rrZ/df2.csv for `df2`

Comment: It should be easier to answer if you provided example code. And anyway, SO rules requires an asker to show its research and a honest attempt...

Comment: `df1[df1.columns[:-1]] = df2`

Comment: @SergeBallesta I tried this way: `df1[0:8]=df2`, What is wrong in it?

Comment: @luigigi Its not working!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame({0:[1,1,1,0,0,0],1:[0,1,0,0,0,0],2:[1,1,1,0,0,0],3:[0,0,0,2,3,4],4:[0,0,0,0,1,0],5:[0,0,0,2,1,2]})

df2=pd.DataFrame({6:[2,2,2,0,0,0],7:[0,2,0,0,0,0],8:[2,2,2,0,0,0],'d':[0,0,0,2,3,4],'e':[0,0,0,0,1,0],'f':[0,0,0,2,1,2]})

z=pd.concat([df1.iloc[:,3:],df2.iloc[:,0:3]],axis=1)
```

Here I have concatenated from  3rd column to last column of 1st dataframe and the first 3 column of 2nd dataframe. Similarly you concatenate whichever row or column you want to concatenate

Comment: Plz do it for the variable shared above